# How to add to an existing shape layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shapes

I am watching [a tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIic9IVr384) in which the instructor added a shape to an existing layer, but I don't know how he did it.

His cursor was an arrow, he began dragging from off the canvas (top left), then dragged to the bottom right of the below image. As a result, the pink rounded rectangle that is selected in the image filled up the bottom corners of the image.

I know that holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> will add to the current layer, but a) His cursor was definitely an arrow rather than a big and small cross shape, so I don't think he did that, b) Keeping <kbd>Shift</kbd> held ALSO constrained the proportions of the new shape that I was adding to the current layer. I even selected the "Unconstrained" from the options but it still comes out as a square...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:

First: Add a new shape (path) to an existing shape (path):
 1. Select the shape (the path itself, not the layer) using the Path
    Selection Tool / Direct Selection Tool (shortcut: A).

1. Select one of the shape tools (shortcut: U).
2. Hit (Shift) and start dragging, this will add the new path to the already selected path.
3. You can let go of the Shift key while dragging in order to leave the dimensions
   unconstrained.

Second: Copy a path from another layer:
 1. Select the desired path (not layer).

1. Hit Ctrl+C.
2. Select a path in the destination layer.
3. Hit Ctrl+V

Comment: Hello Mahmoud, and welcome to GDSE! Thank you for your contribution. When you're specifying steps in a how-to, you can use the 'numbered list' button to make your post more legible.

Comment: Thanks. The first method works well, but neither method explains how he could have done this with the cursor as an arrow rather than the two crosses! Not ultimately material, so I've accepted.